# Missing permissions error message right after login

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication, reactfire

I have an "Uncaught FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions." error when I sign into my app. The problem occurs on the redirection immediately after login. I currently have no error boundaries so a blank white screen with this error message appears in the web console.

I use the reactfire library.

Here some code:

My entry point: (index.tsx)

```js
createRoute(document.getElementById('root')!).render(
  <FirebaseAppProvider firebaseConfig={firebaseConfig}>
    <SuspenseWithPerf fallback={"Loading..."} traceId={'web-initial-loading'}>
      <Wrapper />
    </SuspenseWithPerf>
  </FirebaseAppProvider>
);
```

then the wrapper which just redirect to signin or dashboard depending on authentication:

```js
export const Wrapper = () => <AuthCheck fallback={<SignIn/>}><Dashboard/></AuthCheck>;
```

The important part of my signin page is the sign in button:

```js
<Button onClick={async () => auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)}>
   Sign In
</Button>
```

When I click on the button, there is a small delay caused by the fetching of the user and validation of password, etc (I should put a loading there later, but that is not a problem currently). Then the page turns white with errors in the console.

The page causing the error is the dashboard page. Here the code causing the error:

```js
const user = useUser<User>();
console.log('id', user.uid); // it is ok

const accountRef = useFirestore().collection('users').doc(user.uid);
const account = useFirestoreDocDataOnce<Account>(accountRef);
console.log('account', account); // it is also ok

const companyRef = useFirestore().collection('companies').doc(account.company);
const contractsCollectionRef = companyRef.collection('contracts');
const contracts = useFirestoreCollectionData<Contract>(contractsCollectionRef, { idField: 'id' });
console.log(contracts); // never shown
```

The important thing to note is that if I refresh the page, then the AuthCheck takes me directly to the dashboard and everything is working like expected.

Do you see what I should do to make it work when I sign in too?

It doesn't work with , useUser() and useAuth() from reactfire.  It also doesn't auth() from firebase.

**EDIT**
As a temporary patch, I can change the sign in button's onClick method to that:

```js
() => auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(() => window.location.reload())
```

It's fast enough and on refresh, everything works fine. But I think it would be best to work without the reload.

**EDIT 2**
The same problem persists using react-router lib

index.ts

```js
<HashRouter>
   <AuthCheck fallback={<SignIn/>}>
       <Route path={'/dashboard'}>
           <Dashboard/>
       </Route>
   </AuthCheck>
</HashRouter>
```

SignIn.ts button onClick:

```
onClick={() => auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(() => history.push('/dashboard'))}
```

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing, today.

Comment: I have not found a solution yet so if you find one I would appreciate if you share it. @AlfEaton

Comment: @AlfEaton I posted an answer. Not sure if it can help you in your case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears to be a bug in reactfire. See https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/reactfire/discussions/228.

A possible [workaround](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/reactfire/discussions/228#discussioncomment-182830) is mentioned there suggesting to call the following function immediately after signing out:

```js
export const clearFirestoreCache = () => {
  const map = globalThis['_reactFirePreloadedObservables'];
  Array.from(map.keys()).forEach(
    (key) => key.includes('firestore') && map.delete(key),
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed it when I added a routing system (react-router-dom)
.
index.ts

```js
<ThemeProvider theme={AppTheme}>
    <FirebaseAppProvider firebaseConfig={firebaseConfig}>
      <SnackbarProvider maxSnack={6}>
        <SuspenseWithPerf fallback={<Loader/>} traceId={'web-initial-loading'}>
          <HashRouter>
              <Route path={'/signIn'}>
                <SignIn/>
              </Route>
              <Route path={'/dashboard'}>
                <Dashboard/>
              </Route>
          </HashRouter>
        </SuspenseWithPerf>
      </SnackbarProvider>
    </FirebaseAppProvider>
  </ThemeProvider>
```

And I added a redirect to dashboard on login and a redirect on signIn on logout.

I will have to find a way to handle auto signOut if not loggedIn while on a secured page. But from what I understand, we cannot rely directly on useAuth or  for more complex routing than showing a component. If you make call that needs to be authenticated to work, you better use a real routing system.

**EDIT**
To automatically redirect to sign in page and remember where you were you can replace

```js
<Route path={'/dashboard'}>
    <Dashboard/>
</Route>
```

with

```js
{
    user
        ? <> // All secured routes
            <Route path={'/dashboard'}>
                <Dashboard />
            </Route>
        </>
        : <Redirect to={`/signIn redirectPath=${history.location.pathname}`} />
}
```

Where `user` is the `useUser()` hook.

Answer (score 0):

As per Thomas Hammerl's answer above, it appears to be a bug in reactfire. See https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/reactfire/discussions/228.

I ran into this issue while upgrading to Firebase 9, but reloading the page after the user signs out was the fix for me:

```
signOut(getAuth())
  .then(() => {
     window.location.reload();
  })
  .catch((e) => {
     // handle error eg
     console.log(e.message);
  });
```

This was suggested in the discussion by epodol as a temporary workaround, hopefully the issue can be fixed in the library soon.